# PHP Regular Expression to remove everything after an underscore

Tags: php, regex, arrays, function

I have an array that contains a number of strings in two formats, these are..

```
'number' e.g 55
'number_number' eg 65_12345
```

I need to generate a regular expression to remove the underscore and any characters after this, so `65_12345` would become `65`, Can anyone suggest a simple expression to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use a regex? The function [`strstr`](http://php.net/strstr) can do this easily:

```
$num = '65_12345';
echo strstr($num, '_', true); // 65
```

**For replacing an array of numbers, all having the same format:**

```
$numArr = ['65_12345','223_43434','5334_23332'];

array_walk($numArr, function(&$v) {
    $v = strstr($v, '_', true);
});

print_r($numArr);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 65
    [1] => 223
    [2] => 5334
)
```

Comment: good point.. my mind was just thinking about regex for some reason

Comment: @Zabs, Yeah its better to avoid regex for such small operations :)

Comment: some great answers from everyone thanks :) I've used a slight variation of your answer so accepted yours.

Answer (score 5):

Use the preg_replace for the **regex** way

```
echo  preg_replace('~(\d+)_\d+~',"$1",'65_12345');
```

Use `explode` for **non-regex** way

```
echo explode('_','65_12345')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

This can do what you want, but why regex?

```
#_.*#
```

A fast version:

```
substr('65_678789', 0, strpos('65_678789', '_'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If regex:

```
$string = preg_replace("/_.*/", "", $string);
```

`_.*` means anything after underscore with the underscore.